# Embeded OSGi (Felix) bundle start BundleException : missing requirement

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, osgi, osgi-bundle

I've got an embeded OSGi framework (Felix).
I'm installing the basic bundles without problem, I can access the Felix webconsole.

But starting libra-commons-osgi-core-wsbundle-1.4.0.war gives me this error : 
"org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve hu.libra.commnos.osgi.core.wsbundle [9](R 9.0): missing requirement [hu.libra.commnos.osgi.core.wsbundle [9](R 9.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=hu.libra.commnos.osgi.core.service) Unresolved requirements: [[hu.libra.commnos.osgi.core.wsbundle [9](R 9.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=hu.libra.commnos.osgi.core.service)]"

hu.libra.commnos.osgi.core.service bundle is installed and started (Felix webconsole shows bundle as Active and shows the registered service)

hu.libra.commnos.osgi.core.service\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF contains

Export-Package: hu.libra.commons.osgi.core.service;version="1.4.0";uses:="org.osgi.framework"

hu.libra.commnos.osgi.core.wsbundle\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF contains

Import-Package: org.osgi.framework;version="[1.8,2)",javax.servlet,jav
 ax.servlet.http,hu.libra.commnos.osgi.core.service

What is the problem? Thank You!

My embeded Framework :

.java

```
package hu.libra.commons.osgi.core;


import static org.osgi.framework.Constants.FRAGMENT_HOST;
import static org.osgi.framework.Constants.FRAMEWORK_STORAGE_CLEAN;
import static org.osgi.framework.Constants.FRAMEWORK_STORAGE_CLEAN_ONFIRSTINIT;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.ServiceLoader;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;
import org.osgi.framework.Bundle;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleException;
import org.osgi.framework.launch.Framework;
import org.osgi.framework.launch.FrameworkFactory;

public class LibraOSGiCore {


    //LOGGING
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(LibraOSGiCore.class);


    //FIELDS
    private static final Framework framework;
    private static final List<Bundle> bundleList = new LinkedList<>();


    //CONSTRUCTORS
    static {
        try {
            //log4j
            PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");

            //config
            Map<String, String> config = new HashMap<>();
            config.put(FRAMEWORK_STORAGE_CLEAN, FRAMEWORK_STORAGE_CLEAN_ONFIRSTINIT);
            setConfig(config);

            //framework
            FrameworkFactory frameworkFactory = ServiceLoader.load(FrameworkFactory.class).iterator().next();
            framework = frameworkFactory.newFramework(config);
            framework.start();
        }
        catch (RuntimeException | BundleException e) {
            log.fatal(e, e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }


    //MAIN
    public static void main(
        String[] args) {

        try {
            try {
                installBundles();
                startBundles();
            }
            catch (IOException | BundleException e) {
                log.fatal(e, e);
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            try {
                framework.waitForStop(0);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                return;
            }
        }
        finally {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }


    //METHODS - private
    private static void setConfig(
        Map<String, String> config) {

        //TODO use config.xml
        config.put("org.osgi.service.http.port", "8181");
        //config.put("felix.webconsole.username", "...");
        //config.put("felix.webconsole.password", "...");
    }

    private static Bundle installBundle(
        String name,
        String postfix,
        String ext)
        throws IOException,
            BundleException {

        if (postfix != null) {
            postfix = "-" + postfix;
        }
        else {
            postfix = "";
        }
        String resourceName = name + postfix + "." + ext;
        InputStream is;
        File file = new File(resourceName);
        if (file.exists()) {
            is = new FileInputStream(file);
        }
        else {
            is = LibraOSGiCore.class.getResourceAsStream(resourceName);
        }
        try(InputStream xis = is) {
            Bundle bundle = framework.getBundleContext().installBundle("file:/" + name + "." + ext, is);
            return bundle;
        }
    }

    private static void installBundles()
        throws IOException,
            BundleException {

        //Felix basic bundles
        bundleList.add(installBundle("org.apache.felix.log", "1.0.1", "jar"));
        bundleList.add(installBundle("org.apache.felix.configadmin", "1.8.12", "jar"));
        bundleList.add(installBundle("org.apache.felix.eventadmin", "1.4.8", "jar"));
        bundleList.add(installBundle("org.apache.felix.http.servlet-api", "1.1.2", "jar"));
        bundleList.add(installBundle("org.apache.felix.http.api", "3.0.0", "jar"));

        //Felix Jetty bundle
        bundleList.add(installBundle("org.apache.felix.http.jetty", "3.4.0", "jar"));

        //Felix Webconsole bundle
        bundleList.add(installBundle("org.apache.felix.webconsole", "4.2.16-all", "jar"));

        //Core bundles
        bundleList.add(installBundle("libra-commons-osgi-core-service", "1.4.0", "jar"));
        bundleList.add(installBundle("libra-commons-osgi-core-wsbundle", "1.4.0", "war"));
    }


    private static void startBundles()
        throws BundleException {

        for (Bundle bundle : bundleList) {
            if (bundle.getHeaders().get(FRAGMENT_HOST) != null)
                continue;

            bundle.start();
        }
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>hu.libra.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>libra-commons-osgi-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
    <name>Libra Common OSGi Core</name>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
                <plugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                  <extensions>true</extensions>
                  <executions>
                    <execution>
                      <id>bundle-manifest</id>
                      <phase>process-classes</phase>
                      <goals>
                        <goal>manifest</goal>
                      </goals>
                      <configuration>
                        <instructions>
                          <Bundle-SymbolicName>hu.libra.commnos.osgi.core</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                        </instructions>
                      </configuration>
                    </execution>
                  </executions>
                  <configuration>
                    <supportedProjectTypes>
                      <supportedProjectType>jar</supportedProjectType>
                      <supportedProjectType>bundle</supportedProjectType>
                    </supportedProjectTypes>
                  </configuration>
                </plugin>               
        </plugins>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- OSGi -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.felix.framework</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

hu.libra.commnos.osgi.core.service pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>hu.libra.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>libra-commons-osgi-core-service</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
    <name>Libra Common OSGi Core Service Bundle</name>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins> 
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>       
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>bundle-manifest</id>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>manifest</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <supportedProjectTypes>
                        <supportedProjectType>jar</supportedProjectType>
                        <supportedProjectType>bundle</supportedProjectType>
                    </supportedProjectTypes>
                    <instructions>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>hu.libra.commons.osgi.core.service</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                        <Bundle-Activator>hu.libra.commons.osgi.core.service.Activator</Bundle-Activator>
                        <Export-Package>hu.libra.commons.osgi.core.service</Export-Package>
                    </instructions>                 
                </configuration>
            </plugin>           
        </plugins>      
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- OSGi -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

hu.libra.commnos.osgi.core.wsbundle pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>hu.libra.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>libra-commons-osgi-core-wsbundle</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
    <name>Libra Common OSGi Core Webservice Bundle</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
                <plugin>
                  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                  <configuration>
                    <archive>
                      <manifestFile>${project.build.outputDirectory}/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
                    </archive>
                  </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                  <extensions>true</extensions>
                  <executions>
                    <execution>
                      <id>bundle-manifest</id>
                      <phase>process-classes</phase>
                      <goals>
                        <goal>manifest</goal>
                      </goals>
                    </execution>
                  </executions>
                  <configuration>
                    <supportedProjectTypes>
                      <supportedProjectType>war</supportedProjectType>
                    </supportedProjectTypes>
                        <instructions>
                          <Bundle-SymbolicName>hu.libra.commnos.osgi.core.wsbundle</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                          <Bundle-Activator>hu.libra.commons.osgi.core.wsbundle.Activator</Bundle-Activator>
                          <Private-Package>hu.libra.commons.osgi.core.wsbundle</Private-Package>                          
                          <Import-Package>
                            org.osgi.framework,
                            javax.servlet,
                            javax.servlet.http,
                            javax.servlet.*,
                            javax.servlet.jsp.*,
                            javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.*,
                            hu.libra.commnos.osgi.core.service
                          </Import-Package>
                          <DynamicImport-Package>
                            javax.*,
                            org.xml.sax,
                            org.xml.sax.*,
                            org.w3c.*
                          </DynamicImport-Package>
                          <Bundle-ClassPath>.,WEB-INF/classes</Bundle-ClassPath>
                          <Embed-Directory>WEB-INF/lib</Embed-Directory>
                          <Web-ContextPath>/libraosgicore</Web-ContextPath>
                          <Webapp-Context>/libraosgicore</Webapp-Context>
                        </instructions>
                  </configuration>
                </plugin>           
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- OSGi -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>       

        <!-- Libra OSGi Core Service -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>hu.libra.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>libra-commons-osgi-core-service</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- WS -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.10</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: In your post you have "commnos" instead of (as I would assume) "commons"! Is that a typo in your question or in your bundle's MANIFEST?

Comment: I'd say that's exactly the problem, @MilenDyankov. One bundle is exporting package `hu.libra.commons.osgi.core.service` and the other wants to import `hu.libra.commnos.osgi.core.service`

Comment: I can't belive it was a typo. O.oThank you!

Comment: The fact that this was a typo indicates that you are manually creating your Import-Package statement in `libra-commons-osgi-core-wsbundle-1.4.0.war`. You should not be doing this! Manual manifest management is one of the reasons people think OSGi is hard, and it's completely unnecessary, there are several tools that will generate the manifest for you, the most popular being bnd.